# JQuery.address - remove # from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deep-linking

I'm currently using the jquery.address plugin to achieve deep linking.

For example, I want to load test1.html. I click on the link and it shows on the address bar  /#/test1.
I'd like to show only /test1 without the hashtag. I use PHP in case of a user reload the page.

Here is my code :

JS -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$("document").ready(function(){

    function loadURL(url) {
        console.log("loadURL: " + url);
        $("#area").load(url);
    }


    // Event handlers
    $.address.init(function(event) {
        console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
    }).change(function(event) {
        $("#area").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
        console.log("change");
    })

    $('a').click(function(){
        loadURL($(this).attr('href').replace('', /^#/));
    });

    });

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<a href="test1.html" rel="address:/test1">Test 1</a> <br />
<a href="test2.html" rel="address:/test2">Test 2</a> <br /> <br /> <br />

Load Area: <br />
<div id="area"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your syntax for `replace` is backwards

Answer (score 0):

[String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
loadURL($(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, ''));
```

edit: Note that `^` means ["beginning of string"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in a regex. This means it would not match anything in the string `"/#/test1"`. If you want to strip the `/#/` you should be using this:

```
'/#/test1'.replace(/\/#\//, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wD7LZ/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work.

It was just a test the replace function but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @JeremyWagemans well `^` means "beginning of string" in a regex, so that would not match anything in "/#/page.htm".

Answer (score 0):

Why not split it and take the last section?

```
var urlArray = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
var page = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
loadURL(page);
```

Comment: @JeremyWagemans Try again, I had used parentheses instead of brackets. Edited with new code